# Javascript toLowerCase strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, unicode

I have a small application that reads tweets and tries to match keywords and I noticed this strange behaviour with a particular string:

```
var text = "The Νіk​е D​un​k​ Ніgh ЅΒ 'Uglу Ѕwеаt​еr​' іѕ n​оw аvаіlаblе http://swoo.sh/IHVaTL";
var lowercase = text.toLowerCase()
```

Now the value of lowercase is:

> the νіk​е d​un​k​ ніgh ѕβ 'uglу ѕwеаt​еr​' іѕ n​оw аvаіlаblе
>   http://swoo.sh/ihvatl

So it seems like the string is in a weird format, I double checked some of the letters and found that:

```
text.charAt(4)
>"N"
text.charCodeAt(5)
>925
'N'.charCodeAt(0)
>78
```

So even if it looks like a normal N, the unicode associated to it corresponds to

> 0925 थ DEVANAGARI LETTER THA

according to the [unicode chart](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0900.pdf)

So I´m a bit puzzled about how this can happen, and if there is anyway to "convert" to the supposed real letter

Comment: After copy&paste I could reproduce your error in Firebug, after I've deleted and reinsterted the characters in question manually, not. Where does the string come from? If you typed this in some editor, maybe check your locale/character encoding settings.

Comment: Yep, the "N" in the string contains letters that _look_ like your usual characters, but are in fact characters from the _Greek_ alphabet.

Comment: Apparently someone has her own "translator" like this one http://n00b.camzmac.com/ (not the one though).

Comment: the text was retrieved from Twitter, the application reads from the Twitter stream and this particular one was originated from the Nike account, I just realized about it by chance.

Comment: 'N' in Nike is (039D)hex, 'v' in vike is (03BD)hex which is lowercase.

Comment: Even more bizarre is that the toUpperCase method seems to be working correctly...

Comment: Because all of the homoglyphs in that string are already uppercased. The only way to do this reliably is by comparing images or making a huge list of all homoglyphs in Unicode, and there are tons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a separate canvas with each Latin letter, upper case and lower case, to compare against. Each time you encounter a character that's not in the Latin-1 range, create a new canvas for it, and compare it against each Latin alphabet character using an [image diff](https://github.com/HumbleSoftware/js-imagediff/) algorithm. Replace the non-Latin character with the closest match.

For example:

```
var latinize = (function () {
    var latinLetters = [],
        canvases = [],
        size = 16,
        halfSize = size >> 1;

    function makeCanvas(chr) {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        canvas.width = size;
        canvas.height = size;
        context.textBaseline = 'middle';
        context.textAlign = 'center';
        context.font = (halfSize) + "px sans-serif";
        context.fillText(chr, halfSize, halfSize);

        return context;
    }

    function nextChar(chr) {
        return String.fromCharCode(chr.charCodeAt(0) + 1);
    }

    function setupRange(from, to) {
        for (var chr = from; chr <= to; chr = nextChar(chr)) {
            latinLetters.push(chr);
            canvases.push(makeCanvas(chr));
        }
    }

    function calcDistance(ctxA, ctxB) {
        var distance = 0,
            dataA = ctxA.getImageData(0, 0, size, size).data,
            dataB = ctxB.getImageData(0, 0, size, size).data;

        for (var i = dataA.length; i--;) {
            distance += Math.abs(dataA[i] - dataB[i]);
        }

        return distance;
    }

    setupRange('a', 'z');
    setupRange('A', 'Z');
    setupRange('', ''); // ignore blank characters

    return function (text) {
        var result = "",
            scores, canvas;

        for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
            if (text.charCodeAt(i) < 128) {
                result += text.charAt(i);
                continue;
            }
            scores = [];
            canvas = makeCanvas(text.charAt(i));
            for (var j = 0; j < canvases.length; j++) {
                scores.push({
                    glyph: latinLetters[j],
                    score: calcDistance(canvas, canvases[j])
                });
            }
            scores.sort(function (a, b) {
                return a.score - b.score;
            });
            result += scores[0].glyph;
        }

        return result;
    }
}());
```

This translates your test string to "the nike dunk high sb 'ugly sweater' is now available".

The alternative is to create a giant data structure mapping all of the look-alike characters to their Latin-1 equivalents, as the library in @willy's answer does. This is extremely heavy for "browser JavaScript", and probably not suitable for sending to the client, as you can see by looking at the source for that project.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ly5Lt/4/

Comment: Hi Dagg, thanks for the tip, but I see the solution is "returning the k dunk gh  'ugl wtr'  nw vlbl http://swoo.sh/ihvatl", so it`s removing all the homoglyphs

Comment: @jasalguero, what browser are you using? It works for me in chrome. The problem is that this imagediff library doesn't seem to have a way to score matches, it can only do a full diff or check if two images are "equal" with a fudge factor (which I left out of this example, so the glyphs have to be identical to match; something like different spacing or antialiasing could throw it off). This code was just meant as an example of what you'd have to do to get something like this to work, but I can fix it up if you really want to use it (as ugly as this is, I doubt you'll find another solution).

Comment: Alright, updated it, ditched the library. This version successfully translates `Ï đōń'ţ ķńŏŵ` to `I don't know`, so it should work pretty well for Nike's weird tweets. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: @jasalguero, thanks, glad it works for you. I'm pretty happy with how it came out, doesn't seem as hacky as I first thought. The difference in upvotes between the question and these two answers leaves me wondering what kind of answer people were hoping for, though. Other than the techniques in these two answers, I'm pretty sure there's no other way to do this. Would be interested to hear the thoughts of anyone who upvoted the question.

Comment: Indeed, I'm also surprised about it, taking into account I upvoted both of the answers because both were helpful but yours was the most. Btw, thanks again!!

Answer (score 2):

There is a python library called [unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode/0.04.1) that I've used to solve this problem in python before, it basically "flattens" unicode into ascii.

A quick google reveals that a [similar](http://blog.fgribreau.com/2012/05/unidecode-for-javascript-nodejs.html) library is available for JavaScript.

Comment: How would you use this in a browser? It looks like an npm package to me.

Comment: D,oh! Didn't think fully about your use case. There's an npm module called [browserify](https://npmjs.org/package/browserify) that allows you to `require` modules like in node.